# Android Firebase Realtime Database internet connection

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a way to distinguish when there is no Internet connection in the Android Firebase Realtime Database?

Comment: To check whether a user has internet connectivity, or not, please check the duplicate to see the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to check if user is connected to database or so.
To check that Firebase has a special reference which you can use to detect connection state:

```
DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
        if (connected) {
            Log.d(TAG, "connected");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "not connected");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Listener was cancelled");
    }
});
```

You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#java_8)